# Ошибка cannot find symbol loadAnimation при работе с AnimationUtils

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня возникает ошибка при попытке создать анимацию.

Вот код моей activity:

```java
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.material.animation.AnimationUtils;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button fadeIn, fadeOut;
    ImageView imageView;
    Animation animFadeIn, animFadeOut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        fadeIn = findViewById(R.id.fade_in);
        fadeOut = findViewById(R.id.fade_out);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        fadeIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
            }
        });

        fadeOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_out);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.startAnimation(animFadeOut);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

В Android Studio `loadAnimation` светится красным...

[image: скриншот ошибки, код в MainActivity.java]

как это исправить?

Вот текст ошибки:

```
C:\Users\Oleg\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\test\MainActivity.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
                animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
                                           ^
  symbol:   method loadAnimation(AccessControlContext,int)
  location: class AnimationUtils
```

Comment: А поподробнее нельзя? Кто светится? Где светится? Может приведете код для примера? Мы же не можем по кофейной гуще гадать?

Comment: Вставил скриншот

Comment: В правом верхнем углу редактора будет небольшая кнопка с количеством ошибок и предупреждений разного уровня. Если на нее нажать, то внизу появится панель со списком ошибок и замечаний в данном файле

Comment: Что там написано?

Comment: C:\Users\Oleg\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\test\MainActivity.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
                animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
                                           ^
  symbol:   method loadAnimation(AccessControlContext,int)
  location: class AnimationUtils

Comment: Вот, отлично! это уже что-то! вставьте это в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: А теперь приведите содержимое ресурсов. Вам говорят что соответствующая анимация не была найдена. Это значит что либо ее там нет, либо вам нужно пересобрать проект для того чтобы сгенерировались константы в классе R

Comment: хотя нет...это может быть и из-за того что IDE просто не может найти метод

Comment: это в android studio

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что компилятор не может найти метод в AnimationUtils. Это может быть из-за того что вы импортировали другой класс с таким же названием но другой реализацией, с тем что вы используете другую версию андроида, в которой данного метода нет. Либо же вы скопировали код с невидимыми символами, либо опечаткой...либо могли допустить опечатку сами...к примеру нечаянно туда могла кириллица нечаянно пробраться. Попробуйте стереть название метода и проверить - выдается ли данный метод в автокомплите. Если да - то выбирайте его и посмотрите есть ли метод или нет.

Comment: в автокомплите не выдаёт такого метода

Comment: также можете привести полный код класса в виде текста со всеми импортами

Comment: добавил в вопрос весь код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что компилятор не может найти метод `loadAnimation` в классе `AnimationUtils`.

Это может быть из-за того что

- вы импортировали другой класс с таким же названием но другой реализацией
- вы используете другую версию андроида, в которой данного метода нет
- вы скопировали код с невидимыми символами, либо опечаткой...
- либо могли допустить опечатку сами...к примеру нечаянно туда могла кириллица нечаянно пробраться.

В вашем случае случилось первое - вы импортировали другой класс `AnimationUtils`

Замените строку

```java
import com.google.android.material.animation.AnimationUtils;
```

на

```java
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
```

по идее все должно заработать.

Comment: Миша, ты Лучший. Всё сработало. Спасибо большое)))

Comment: @OlegMan, удачи вам

Comment: Огромное спасибо....то я уже 2 дня голову ломаю

Comment: @OlegMan, пишите вопросы если будут. Только оформляйте их получше) код там прикладывайте, тексты ошибок и ворнингов)

Comment: Хорошо, ясно) Я первый раз вопрос задаю, ещё не в курсе что к чему тут

Comment: @OlegMan, можете почитать справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking . Новичкам непросто порой приходится на stackoverflow. Но если знать правила - то все будет хорошо)

Comment: спасибо вам) Удачи)